# How to see Archive Box

Tags: mail.app, archive

The Archive Box is not displayed in my Sidebar, yet I can archive mail.
How do I get the Archive Folder to display, so i can retrieve my archived emails?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to go to you on-lie gmail account and there turn of the "All Mail"

In gmail (on-line) click on the gear (top right), and select Settings.

In settings select "Labels" find the All Mail and enable "show in IMAP".

Your are done, it should now show as Archive folder in your Mac Mail.